# Ключевое слово "is"

Tags: c#

Подскажите почему возникают ошибки.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return obj is mainClass mC && mC.x == this.x && mC.y == this.y;
}
```

Получаю ошибку в этой строке `obj is mainClass mC` :

> Ошибка    1   В качестве оператора могут использоваться только выражения присваивания, вызова, инкремента, декремента, ожидания и создания нового объекта
>   Ошибка  2   Элемент "mC" не существует в текущем контексте.
>   Ошибка  3   Требуется ";"

Comment: Посмотрите в настройках проекта, какая версия C# выбрана. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enabling-c-sharp-7-compilation-with-visual-studio-2017/ Должна быть 7.0 или 7.1. Если их в списке нет, значит, надо установить.

Answer (score 3):

**Для версии C# >= 7.0:** данный код абсолютно правильный и не вызывает никаких ошибок во время компиляции/выполнения.

---

**Для версии C# < 7.0:**

```
return obj is mainClass mC && mC.x == this.x && mC.y == this.y;
```

После этого выражения `obj is mainClass` компилятор ожидает либо `;`, что означает что выражение закончено, либо другой оператор. У вас же идет дальше переменная `mC`, причем не определенная в контексте метода.

Скорее всего вам нужно было написать код так:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var mC = obj as mainClass;
    return mC != null && mC.x == this.x && mC.y == this.y;
}
```

Здесь я использовал оператор `as` который аналогичен операции приведения с одной разницей- если приведение невозможно произвести в переменную запишется `null`. Далее мы ее проверяем первым условием, и дальше идет проверка вашей логики.

Однако не забудьте еще один момент- если вы переопределяете метода `Equals()`, вам нужно переопределить метод `GetHashCode()`.

Answer (score -4):

Мне кажется что переменная mC появится только после проверки всего условия.

Я бы написал эту функцию вот так:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    bool result = false;
    if (obj is mainClass mC)
    {
        result = mC.x == this.x && mC.y == this.y;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @Anamnian, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#pattern-matching

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо, не знал.